# JDBC plugin feeder mode find class error in feed script

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm following the instructions in this link - https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc/wiki/JDBC-plugin-feeder-mode-as-an-alternative-to-the-deprecated-Elasticsearch-River-API

- ES - 1.7.0
- JDBC - 1.7.0.1

My feed script and all structure looks like:

```
enter code 
#!/bin/bash

# ES_HOME required to detect elasticsearch jars

export ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch

echo '
{
"elasticsearch" : {
     "cluster" : "elasticsearch",
     "host" : "localhost",
     "port" : 9300
},
"type" : "jdbc",
"jdbc" : {
    "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb",
    "user" : "---",
    "password" : "---",
    "sql" :  "select * FROM table",
    "index":"index",
    "type":"type"
  }
}
' | java \
-cp "${ES_HOME}/lib/*:${ES_HOME}/plugins/jdbc/*" \
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=${ES_HOME}/lib/log4j.properties \
org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.feeder.Runner \
org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.feeder.JDBCFeeder
```

And I'm getting this error all the time:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.feeder.Runner